# how do i divide 2 varchar2 columns?

Tags: sql

Need to divide 2 varchar columns

tried cast function to convert varchar to number

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Please show your query and the error (or wrong result) you got! Normally, `CAST` or `TO_NUMBER` should work fine for Oracle

Comment: Oracle ..tried both cast and to_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put sample below for SQL Server. I am explicitly casting both dividend(10 below) & divisor (2 below) for clarity in the programming.

```
DECLARE @value1 VARCHAR(10) = '10'
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(10) = '2'

SELECT CAST(@Value1 AS INT) / CAST(@Value2 AS INT)
```

Comment: i have 2 columns quantity and price of (varchar2)